# docker login not working with nexus 3 private registry

Tags: nginx, docker, nexus

[Nexus UI Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlGWN.png)

I am running Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.0.1-01 on a linux VM
On that VM, I have nginx working to reserve proxy http requests as https.
My SSL key is signed by a trusted CA
I created a maven repository, which works without issues, whenever I have a client machine publish to it.

Also on this client machine, when I use my docker client, and do a docker login. I am receiving all kinds of errors.

I am following these instructions https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/docker.html#_accessing_repositories
Specifically Section 9.2 and honestly, I've spent the last 2 days getting nowhere.

I've read over everything that's mentioned here:
[Trouble connecting to Docker registry stored on Nexus 3 Preview on Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021350/trouble-connecting-to-docker-registry-stored-on-nexus-3-preview-on-azure-vm)
But that setup the user explains confuses me.

For the setup we are trying to achieve insecure settings by adding `--insecure-registry` to `/etc/default/docker` file, is simply not 
an option.

I've tried to follow multiple tutorials just to understand the inner workings of the docker registry but I haven't been able to piece
it together. I've looked at following this to a certain extent:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04

I have used additional responses in stackoverflow to help me troubleshoot
[malformed HTTP response with docker private registry (v2) behind an nginx proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599634/malformed-http-response-with-docker-private-registry-v2-behind-an-nginx-proxy)

But honestly I can't say I've found anything that's made understanding this straight forward. NGINX isn't reporting any error logs
in `/var/log/nginx/errors.log`, the access logs look like basic 'GETS', each time I attempt a docker login. 
The docker logs in 
`/var/log/upstart/docker.log` report the same errors that I'm illustrating below with the 404 errors.
Also followed this issue on github to see if that was any help github com/docker/docker/issues/8410 . Any assistance to get me to able to perform a successful docker login to this private nexus 3 repo would be amazing.

Now maybe I'm a bit confused with everything I've been reading to get my docker client to work successfully with this nexus repo, but is it required that I setup a docker(group) repo and that is the source of my issue? Or is it okay for me to just have a docker(hosted) repo. Because as of right now I only have a docker(hosted) repo. The Nexus documentation didn't give me the impression that a group repo was also required to get things to work.

Last but not least, I hope my question is specific enough, and I hope that you guys see I've made some effort here. I really did try!

When I login, I am using the local admin user, with the default admin password.
First let me present the issues:

If I try without a port, i get the following --

```
root:~# docker login box.company.net
Error response from daemon: Login:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>404 - Nexus Repository Manager</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

With the HTTP port of 4444, i get the following

```
root:~# docker login box.company.net:4444
Error response from daemon: Get https://box.company.net:4444/v1/users/: `http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`
```

If I add HTTPS in the Nexus UI to 4445, then I run

```
root:~# docker login box.company.net:4445
Error response from daemon: Get https://box.company.net:4445/v1/users/: dial tcp x.x.x.x:4445: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Here is my environment information:

```
#cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"

# uname -r
3.19.0-65-generic

# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

~# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Thu Aug 18 05:22:43 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Thu Aug 18 05:22:43 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf

server {

    proxy_send_timeout 120;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_buffering    off;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 1G;

    listen 80;
    server_name box.company.net;
    location / {
          rewrite ^(.*) https://box.company.net$1 permanent;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name box.company.net;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/net.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/net.key;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!kEDH:!ADH:!MD5:@STRENGTH;
    ssl_session_cache shared:TLSSSL:16m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
      proxy_pass              http://x.x.x.x:8081;
      proxy_read_timeout      90;

    }
}
```

here are some basic curl results for more info, if this will help at all.

```
 root:~# curl -v https://box.company.net
* Rebuilt URL to: https://box.company.net
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* Connected to box.company.net (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*        subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=*.company.net
*        start date: 2016-04-01 14:01:38 GMT
*        expire date: 2018-04-14 15:15:04 GMT
*        subjectAltName: box.company.net matched
*        issuer: C=US; ST=Arizona; L=Scottsdale; O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.; OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/; CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: box.company.net
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 13:39:14 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 5077
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Last-Modified: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 13:39:14 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Expires: 0
```

Any help to get docker login private.registry.net would be highly helpful thanks.

Comment: This is a bit old now, but I'm experiencing the exact same problems.  Did you eventually solve this?

Comment: Actually yes, I did, let me go grab the solution which worked for me.

Comment: I am experiencing this in 2022 using pretty much the same setup as you. Http connector in nexus, ports open in docker-compose, nginx with additional server blocks. But I am not even getting entries in the docker access logs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to add an additional (server) entry in my nginx config, right below the previous entry

**restart nginx**

docker client, will connect to port 6666, nginx will route the traffic to port 4444 which

```
# correlates to your nexus http connector
server {
    listen 6666;
    server_name box.company.net;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/net.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/net.key;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!kEDH:!ADH:!MD5:@STRENGTH;
    ssl_session_cache shared:TLSSSL:16m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    client_max_body_size 1G;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;

    location / {

      access_log              /var/log/nginx/docker.log;
      proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
      proxy_pass              http://x.x.x.x:4444;
      proxy_read_timeout      90;

    }
}
```

**then I could do**

```
docker login -u username -p password box.company.net:6666
docker pull box.company.net:6666/docker-image:tag
docker push box.company.net:6666/docker-image:tag
```

Comment: Thanks.  just got there myself about an hour ago in a very marginally different way.

Comment: This solution returns me 400 "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" on `docker login -u username -p password box.company.net:6666`. What is your different way @pms1969 ?

Comment: Can you provide me with your nexus ui config?

Comment: Also paste your entire nginx config is possible

Comment: I can't do it on a comment, not enough space. But the same except:
UI repository type `group` and on extra server nginx config I listen on 18444 on both.

Comment: Nevermind, solved. You can't use the same port on `listen` and `proxy_pass`. Thank you.

Comment: I probably should've highlighted that those 2 ports need to be different in the answer.

Comment: Configure as you say, but get `docker login -u admin -p admin123 myhost:5000
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://myhost:5000/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found`

Comment: @burtsevyg There's a good chance that part of this is dated. This could be related to whatever new docker client you're using.

Comment: I came to this solution too but in my case cloudflare was intermingling with the available https ports: see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74025182/nexus-docker-registry-behind-nginx-unreachable). Your answer helped me validate my solution.