# Nexus docker registry behind nginx unreachable

Tags: docker, nginx, digital-ocean, nexus, cloudflare

I have been trying to setup private docker repositories on a nexus, hosted on a digital ocean droplet, with an nginx in front of it. It appears that nexus and the maven repositories are working just fine but the docker repositories are not. The most related answer I could find was this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148462/docker-login-not-working-with-nexus-3-private-registry) but it got me nowhere.

My docker-compose file is configured as following:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3:${NEXUS_VERSION}
    restart: always
    container_name: nexus
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
      - "8090:8090"
      - "8091:8091"
    volumes:
      - ./nexus/data:/nexus-data
      - ./nexus/logs:/opt/sonatype/sonatype-work/nexus3/log

  nginx:
    image: nginx:${NGINX_VERSION}
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8092:8092"
      - "8093:8093"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
      - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/ssl/:ro
      - ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx/
```

My nginx.config:

```
proxy_send_timeout        120;
proxy_read_timeout        300;
proxy_buffering           off;
tcp_nodelay               on;
client_max_body_size      0;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;

server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  location / {
    proxy_pass            http://nexus:8081/;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;
    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}

server {
  listen 8092 ssl;
  
  location / {
    proxy_pass            http://nexus:8090/;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;
    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access-docker-group.log;
  }
}

server {
  listen 8093 ssl;

  location / {
    proxy_pass            http://nexus:8091/;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;
    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access-docker-private.log;
  }
}
```

The output `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` in the droplet:

```
docker-pr 137657            root    4u  IPv4 1088073      0t0  TCP *:8091 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 137664            root    4u  IPv6 1088080      0t0  TCP *:8091 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 137679            root    4u  IPv4 1088811      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 137684            root    4u  IPv6 1088814      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 137698            root    4u  IPv4 1088831      0t0  TCP *:8081 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 137704            root    4u  IPv6 1088834      0t0  TCP *:8081 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 144216            root    4u  IPv4 1108464      0t0  TCP *:8093 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 144222            root    4u  IPv6 1109509      0t0  TCP *:8093 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 144237            root    4u  IPv4 1108483      0t0  TCP *:8092 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 144244            root    4u  IPv6 1109530      0t0  TCP *:8092 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 144257            root    4u  IPv4 1109551      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 144262            root    4u  IPv6 1109554      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 144276            root    4u  IPv4 1109575      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 144281            root    4u  IPv6 1109578      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

But whenever I try to perform a docker login I get the following:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://<domain>:8092/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Both docker access logs are empty so I am guessing my nginx config is wrong but I just don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my setup was correct. The docker login succeeded when I used the IP of the droplet rather then the domain. This hinted to the fact that the custom https ports were somehow blocked. So it occurred to me that cloudflare might be imposing port restrictions. And voila, I found their [network ports reference page](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/network-ports/) and changed the ports in my `docker-compose` and managed to get the `docker login` to work with my domain.

> **HTTPS ports supported by Cloudflare**
>
> 1. 443
> 2. 2053
> 3. 2083
> 4. 2087
> 5. 2096
> 6. 8443

Hope this helps.